# forEach and assign to variable

Tags: javascript

This is just an example that I want to understand. I know there is a better way to select the last element from the array, but I don't know why it works that way.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

let exampleId: number;

numbers.forEach(function(number) {
  exampleId = number;
});

console.log(exampleId);
```

Why do I get the error "Variable 'exampleId' is used before being assigned." in the line from console.log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment is scoped within the `forEach` loop; If `numbers` have no values, `exampleId` would never get defined. TS is essentially warning you about that, as you cannot call a variable that has yet to be defined.

##### Solution 1:

Initialise your variable with a value

```js
let exampleId = 0;
```

##### Solution 2:

Use non-null assertions, although I'd suggest against them

```js
console.log(exampleId!);
```

With this solution we're essentially telling TS to not worry about it, as there will surely exist a value; That, in other words, remove the type safety, reason why I'd suggest going with option 1.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the interpreter doesn't take into account that the array `numbers` is not empty in your code.

Because, if it were empty, for sure the variable `exampleId` would be used before being assigned.

(If the array is empty, the code inside the forEach loop is never executed, and the variable is never assigned)

Answer (score 1):

The way to select the value of the last element from an array is

```
function lastElementOfArray(arr = []) {
  return arr.length > 0
    ? arr[ arr.length - 1 ]
    : undefined
    ;
}
```

The reason you get `Variable 'exampleId' is used before being assigned.` is because there's no guarantee that the `Array.forEach()` callback that assigns a value to `exampleId` will ever be invoked (e.g., when the array `numbers` has a length of 0).

And so, you get that message on the line

```
console.log(exampleId)
```